# Long running background jobs in desktop

Tags: python, windows, printing, windows-services, kivy

> I've a web application, where users need to print pdf files 
>   frequently, The pdf files are generated by django server and send to
>   the client(browser), Clients are using windows machine.

---

Now I want do silent printing, want to do print the pdf files without user's confirmation.

---

My plan is to create a desktop application / python script (all clients will install it),  which listens to 'Download' folder and send the pdf files(generated from my web app)  to the printer, then move the files to another folder. I started implementing it as a kivy application. The main part is it is a long running job which looks for the files in the download folder and execute print command when ever a file found.

There is two parts in the desktop application.

> 1. GUI to configure the download folder, printer etc
> 2. Long running listener which send the pdf file to the printer

I'm a newbie to windows/ desktop applications

1. How can I run a long running python  job in a desktop application in windows.
2. should celery beat / apscheduler solves the issue
3. How can I keep running the listener job even though the GUI application closed.

Currently my plan is to start a windows service from the GUI (or a separate python script as windows service), and restart it when a user changes any configuration(change download folder, printer), is it doable, right approach?.
 Is it possible do without windows service and using celery/apscheduler?.

Even am ready drop the desktop application plan and do a browser extension if its a good choice (I never done it before,  is it doable via extension). Please help me to take a decision, Any help appreciated.

Comment: To me, this sounds like a task for a windows task scheduler. Schedule a python script which runs every hour or every minute whatever you like, similar to cron jobs on linux. So do not make this one long running job, but one short which checks if a new file is in download, if yes do whatever it is supposed to do else do nothing.